# Missing fan data for page after a certain date using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am querying the Facebook Graph API to grab some historical data regarding the number of fans one of our pages had each month for the past year or so but the insights/page_fans endpoint stops returning the number of fans from 11th January 2016 and before.

The page in question has been online for over 2 years so I have no idea why the data for the 11th Jan and before isn't being returned.

As far as I can see in the documentation, the endpoint should be returning the data just fine.

I am calling: `page_id/insights/page_fans?since=1451606400`

(1st January 2016 00:00:00 GMT)

Which returns:

```
{
    "end_time": "2016-01-10T08:00:00+0000"
},
{
    "end_time": "2016-01-11T08:00:00+0000"
},
{
    "value": 60341,
    "end_time": "2016-01-12T08:00:00+0000"
},
{
    "value": 60388,
    "end_time": "2016-01-13T08:00:00+0000"
}
```

I've trawled through the documentation and searched the web for a couple of hours now so any pointers would be very much appreciated as to why the value simply isn't returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here.
It seems to have been broken since v2.4.

A bug ticket has been opened here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1519022225061018/

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue with Graph API 2.5. If you downgrade to Api 2.2 it works just fine.